# pdftoppm fails to create output

Tags: pdf, ocr, pdftoppm

I'm running pdftoppm from command prompt but it fails to create any output.

here is my input

```
c:\test>pdftoppm -r 600 png W10475.pdf test
```

here is what files I have in the associated 'test' directory

```
c:\test>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 32C5-D3A1

 Directory of c:\test

10/11/2017  03:36 PM    <DIR>          .
10/11/2017  03:36 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/06/2017  10:00 PM            42,552 convert.exe
10/06/2017  10:00 PM            42,552 magick.exe
08/08/2017  04:22 PM         1,179,648 pdfinfo.exe
08/08/2017  04:22 PM         1,988,096 pdftoppm.exe
08/08/2017  04:22 PM         1,239,040 pdftotext.exe
06/02/2017  12:24 PM           805,964 tesseract.exe
10/09/2017  02:36 PM         5,076,873 W10475.pdf
10/09/2017  02:37 PM         6,376,241 W10926.pdf
10/09/2017  02:37 PM         7,272,812 W11240.pdf
10/09/2017  02:37 PM        11,403,203 W11285.pdf
10/09/2017  02:37 PM         4,576,258 W11292.pdf
10/09/2017  02:37 PM         5,819,421 W11335.pdf
              12 File(s)     45,822,660 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  53,296,689,152 bytes free
```

And here is the output from my command

```
pdftoppm version 4.00
Copyright 1996-2017 Glyph & Cog, LLC
Usage: pdftoppm [options] <PDF-file> <PPM-root>
  -f <int>          : first page to print
  -l <int>          : last page to print
  -r <number>       : resolution, in DPI (default is 150)
  -mono             : generate a monochrome PBM file
  -gray             : generate a grayscale PGM file
  -freetype <string>: enable FreeType font rasterizer: yes, no
  -aa <string>      : enable font anti-aliasing: yes, no
  -aaVector <string>: enable vector anti-aliasing: yes, no
  -opw <string>     : owner password (for encrypted files)
  -upw <string>     : user password (for encrypted files)
  -q                : don't print any messages or errors
  -cfg <string>     : configuration file to use in place of .xpdfrc
  -v                : print copyright and version info
  -h                : print usage information
  -help             : print usage information
  --help            : print usage information
  -?                : print usage information
```

There are no error messages thrown and no files written to the c:\test folder. I thought pdftoppm.exe would write to the same folder it is called from. Am I mistaken, or is there just no output being written? If that is the case, how do I get it to generate some output.

Comment: I had this problem with a downloaded version of poppler on Ubuntu but not the `poppler-utils` package from the official Ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions become dated over time and the answer is now significantly different for windows users in 2021, however the confusion is often due to **which of the two sets of pdfto### utils** you are running.

First the Question was why the Xpdf command to produce a PNG from Utils is not working as per Poppler utils. However you need to use the dedicated pdftopng exe. (note the G&C pdfto**ppm** help screen above clearly does/did not show -png as an valid output option)

[pdftopng.exe](http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html) -v4.##- converts a PDF file to a series of PNG image files

```
 pdftopng -r 600 file.pdf test
```

will produce output file `test-000001.png` etc.

Note you can add the optional -alpha and there are many other options, here is the current 4.03 help screen.

```
pdftopng --help

pdftopng version 4.03 [www.xpdfreader.com]
Copyright 1996-2021 Glyph & Cog, LLC
Usage: pdftopng [options] <PDF-file> <PNG-root>
  -f <int>          : first page to print
  -l <int>          : last page to print
  -r <number>       : resolution, in DPI (default is 150)
  -mono             : generate a monochrome PNG file
  -gray             : generate a grayscale PNG file
  -alpha            : include an alpha channel in the PNG file
  -rot <int>        : set page rotation: 0, 90, 180, or 270
  -freetype <string>: enable FreeType font rasterizer: yes, no
  -aa <string>      : enable font anti-aliasing: yes, no
  -aaVector <string>: enable vector anti-aliasing: yes, no
  -opw <string>     : owner password (for encrypted files)
  -upw <string>     : user password (for encrypted files)
  -q                : don't print any messages or errors
  -cfg <string>     : configuration file to use in place of .xpdfrc
  -v                : print copyright and version info
  -h                : print usage information
  -help             : print usage information
  --help            : print usage information
  -?                : print usage information
```

For [Poppler 21.##](https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases/) users you will still need to use the pdftoppm command with -png option.

```
poppler-21.09.0\Library\bin> pdftoppm -r 600 -png file.pdf test
```

which will produce a similar output file `test-1.png` etc.

Answer (score -2):

The command must be: `pdftoppm -r 600 -png W10475.pdf test`